# Отправка сообщения на почту C#

Tags: c#, smtp, sendmail

Нашёл образец кода на форуме, сделал всё по шаблону, вроде и отправляет сообщения, а как только другу отправил приложение потестить так приходят сообщения будь-то я их себе отправляю. Как сделать отправку от введенного адреса:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fromUser = richTextBox1.Text;
        int mark = trackBar1.Value;
        string uemail = textBox1.Text;
        try
        {
            MailAddress from = new MailAddress (uemail);
            MailAddress to = new MailAddress ("Мой маил");
            MailMessage m = new MailMessage (from,to);
            m.Subject = "Твое приложение оценили!";
            m.IsBodyHtml = false;
            m.Body = "Your mark is " + mark + "\n" + fromUser;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient ("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
            {
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("Мой маил", "пароль приложения"),
                EnableSsl = true
            };
            smtp.Send (m);
            MessageBox.Show ("Сообщение успешно отправлено. Спасибо!");
            Close ( );
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show ("Неверный формат электронной почты. Почта должна иметь окончания - @gmail/yandex/mail/bk/list и другие");
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show ("Строка с адресом не должна быть пуста");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show (ex.HelpLink);
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну так не отправляйте сами себе

Comment: Кто бы не запускал приложение и не вводил какой либо почту приходят сообщения такого вида

Comment: @AquaGF у вас в переменной `to` (что с английского переводится как `к`, `кому`) записан Ваш email. Какой результат ещё Вы хотели получить??

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, если на то пошло, from /eng - от, от кого/ и там ясно указана переменная которая принимает значение пользовательского ввода. И к тому же я ожидаю что мне скажут как сделать что бы приходили сообщения ОТ пользователей с ИХ адресами

Comment: Я же всё - таки хочу что бы оценка приходила мне на почту от пользователей а не наоборот, согласитесь

Comment: @AquaGF это немного не так работает, сейчас запишу Вам ответ

Comment: Ну давайте хоть так а то пердак горит от ответов на других ресурсах

Comment: Нужно понимать разницу между тем, с какого клиента отправляется сообщение, и что содержится в сообщении. В Вашем случае, вы отправляете сообщение от своего клиента, но подпись "from" может быть какой угодно (не обязательно даже адрес ящика, хоть aaa)

Comment: Я же обработал исключение без которого был краш с ошибкой invalid form of email

Comment: Вы для входа на сервер используете следующие данные:
Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("Мой маил", "пароль приложения")
То есть вы входите в свой почтовый ящик.

Comment: Так а возможно ли реализовать что б от пользователя? Авторизация что ли

Comment: @AquaGF постарался доходчиво объяснить, почему не сработал Ваш пример. Если захотите, потом могу чуть более подробно расписать, как формируются заголовки при отправке писем и зачем они вообще нужны (а также почему некоторые на данный момент игнорируются))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код необходимо переписать следующим образом:

```
string fromUser = richTextBox1.Text;    // Получим комментарий пользователя
int mark = trackBar1.Value;             // Получим оценку приложения
string uemail = textBox1.Text;          // Получим Email пользователя
string upassword = *.Text;              // Нам понадобится и пароль от Email пользователя
                                        // Как Вы понимаете, рассылать что-то от имени
                                        // чужого аккаунта просто так не получится,
                                        // Так что без авторизации никуда!
try
{
    MailAddress from = new MailAddress(uemail);
    MailAddress to = new MailAddress(myEmail);
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to) // Формируем сообщение с нужными заголовками
                                                    // Заголовок "от кого" ныне часто игнорируется,
                                                    // и на его место ставится реальный адрес отправителя,
                                                    // так что подписаться миллионером дядей Петей не получится
    {
        Subject = "Твое приложение оценили!",
        IsBodyHtml = false,
        Body = $"Your mark is {mark}{Environment.NewLine}{fromUser}"
    }; 
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    {
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(uemail, upassword),
        EnableSsl = true
    };
    smtp.Send(message);                             // Отправляем наше письмо
    MessageBox.Show("Сообщение успешно отправлено. Спасибо!");
    Close();
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Неверный формат электронной почты. Почта должна иметь окончания - @gmail/yandex/mail/bk/list и другие");
    textBox1.Clear();
}
catch (ArgumentException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Строка с адресом не должна быть пуста");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.HelpLink);
}
```

---

### Почему так:

Проблема в том, что в Вашем коде Вы проводили авторизацию на SMTP-сервере через **свой** аккаунт!
Тем самым, сформировав письмо, где Вы указали:

> Кому (`to`) = Мне 
> От кого (`from`) = От Пользователя

Вы получили следующий результат: SMTP-клиент, переправляя заданное сообщение, учитывает **только** заголовок, указывающий, `кому` нужно отправить письмо, полностью **игнорируя** заголовок `от кого`, так как вместо него используется реальный адрес отправителя (то есть опять же Ваш email)

---

### Что делать:

Вам необходимо реализовать нечто вроде аутентификации пользователя в его почтовом ящике (учитывайте, что приведенный мной пример, если Вы добавите `TextBox`, содержащий данные о **пароле** пользователя, сработает лишь для аккаунтов `gmail`).
Да и стоит учесть, что не всякий пользователь будет доверять какой-то программе данные от своей учетной записи. Кто же знает, вдруг Вы потом будете использовать их в своих корыстных целях? Так что я считаю, что необходимо полностью поменять подход к данной задаче
Если Ваша программа использует какую-либо удаленную базу знаний, то почему не отправлять запрос сразу к ней? Это было бы самым простым решением. В противном случае Вам придется дорабатывать свой код для аутентификации пользователей от `ЯндексПочты` до самого `iCloud Mail`, что является достаточно объемной задачей

**UPD:**
Я тут подумал, если у Вас нет удаленной БД, и Вам хотелось бы получать именно `Email`-письма, то чем плох вариант отправки писем самому себе? А в заголовке или в теле письма Вы бы уже могли указать, от кого именно получено данное письмо. Вариант, конечно, кривой (к примеру, полностью отсутствует валидация введенного пользователем почтового адреса. Валидность-то можно проверить с помощью `regex`, а вот правда ли данная почта принадлежит пользователю...), однако в рамках Вашей задачи, возможно, Вам этого и хватит)

---

Надеюсь, мой ответ хоть немного прояснил Вашу проблему. Желаю Вам удачно ее разрешить)

Comment: Всё замечательно. Ошибка в string upassword = *.Text ошибка на точке

Comment: @AquaGF Так понятное дело) Я же написал в комментарии к коду (да и чуть ниже в ответе), что понадобится новый `TextBox` для ввода пароля от указанного почтового адреса) Звездочку я поставил, так как не знал, как Вы обзовете новый `TextBox`)

Comment: Всё спасибо а куда мой пароль от почты вводить?

Comment: Потерялся так много текста

Comment: @AquaGF так что вместо звездочки впишите имя нового `TextBox`)

Comment: Нет пароль приложения вы чем заменили

Comment: @AquaGF а пароль от Вашей почты не нужен. Вы ведь не вводите пароль от почты пользователя, **которому** отправляете письмо, верно?)

Comment: Всё спасибо. Буду готов над реализацией авторизации через браузер напишу как новый вопрос. А через браузер вообще возможно реализовать?

Comment: @AquaGF я его таки заменил на `upassword`, как видите, который является паролем от почты пользователя. А пароль от Вашей почты в коде прогонами более не нужен

Comment: @AquaGF вы хотите сделать это через браузер? Как говорится, все, что можно себе представить, можно реализовать с помощью программирования) Так что задавайте новый вопрос, когда Вам это понадобится. А мы уж поможем, кто чем сможет)

Comment: Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ. первый раз в своем вопросе такой вижу. Сначала подумал вопрос пустяковый сейчас начнут дубликаты и т.д.

Comment: @AquaGF пожалуйста) Да понимаете, после настойчивого насаждения у нас `be nice`, этого самого `nice` стало как-то меньше ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯